# how to add data to parameter when using route helper, needed data store inside variable

Tags: laravel

this a tag use in table, so using table data I want to forward id to new page, here I attach my code

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Add ID</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  @foreach($PDFS ?? '' as $PDF)
  <tr>
      <td>{{$PDF->AddID}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{route('ORP_Print_SMID',[app()->getLocale(),'id'=>'{{$PDF->AddID}}']) }}">open</a>
       </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  <tbody></tbody></table>
```

this is not working.

but below code is working

```
<a href="{{ route('ORP_Print_SMID', [app()->getLocale(),'id' => '24']) }}" >find</a>
```

actual data in this variable is '24'

```
{{$PDF->AddID}} =24
```

how I solve this, plz help me

Comment: remove inner `{{}}`. ie, change `{{$PDF->AddID}}` to `$PDF->AddID`. No need to put `{{ }}` inside another `{{ }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `{{ }}` again inside `{{ }}`

**Change**

```
<td><a href="{{route('ORP_Print_SMID',[app()->getLocale(),'id'=>'{{$PDF->AddID}}']) }}">open</a>
```

**to**

```
<td><a href="{{route('ORP_Print_SMID',[app()->getLocale(),'id'=>$PDF->AddID]) }}">open</a>
```

Comment: @sameera when you click on **up arrow** on left side of answer is called **upvote**.